# What is the diffrent between registerclass and registerclassex?

Tags: c++, winapi

Does anybody know's the diffrent between registerclass and registerclassex?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is covered by the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 3):

`RegisterClass` accepts, `WNDCLASS` and `RegisterClassEx` accepts `WNDCLASSEX`.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577.aspx) for `WNDCLASSEX` says:

> The WNDCLASSEX structure is similar to the WNDCLASS structure. There are two differences. WNDCLASSEX includes the cbSize member, which specifies the size of the structure, and the hIconSm member, which contains a handle to a small icon associated with the window class.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586.aspx) for `RegisterClass` says:

> The RegisterClass function has been superseded by the RegisterClassEx function. You can still use RegisterClass, however, if you do not need to set the class small icon.

I suspect that you've not read any of this because you have not yet learnt how to find the documentation. Type the name of the function or type into a search engine, possibly including the term MSDN to narrow down the results, and find the documentation from the returned hits.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Ex-Versions of the API were introduced with 32-bit Windows. They usually supersede the 16-bit Windows API calls, and calls to the old functions map to the new functions, passing default arguments for any additional parameter. The Ex-suffix is necessary, since C doesn't support overloading.